# MYSQL Trigger problem -Very Easy

Tags: mysql, sql, triggers

```
    DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER stock_empty AFTER UPDATE on products
    FOR EACH ROW
    DELETE FROM products WHERE stock <=0;
    END$$
```

I am trying to make my products table check itself after every UPDATE statement and delete rows that have 0 or negative stock counts. I could manage to get this far, but it is not working.

Thanks for any help

Comment: Are you sure you want "stock count"  in the products table?

Comment: yes yes it is not a big project or anything, i'm just messing around with  mysql

Comment: Are you sure you want to remove products you don't have in stock (just now)? I mean, what about returns etc.; will you retain any product information on sold out products?

Comment: i am just trying to learn about triggers dude, i don't care if the table is named products or table1, i just created a dummy scenario

Comment: The problem with dummy scenarios that are not how they are done in the real world, is that bad idioms propagate.... MSDN used to be guilty of this (but largely cleaned up it's act now...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it's that easy, how come you didn't solve it yourself?

```
DELIMITER ||
CREATE TRIGGER stock_empty AFTER UPDATE on products
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
DELETE FROM products WHERE stock <=0;
END ||
```

[edit]

That's how correct syntax should look like, however there's one more thing:

> A stored function or trigger cannot
>   modify a table that is already being
>   used (for reading or writing) by the
>   statement that invoked the function or
>   trigger.

From: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/stored-program-restrictions.html

Comment: +1 just for the subtle jab re "very easy' - I was thinking of adding that myself in a comment but you beat me to it :-)

Comment: nope this did not solve it, i was using delimiters too, i think i should add them

Comment: Did you use BEGIN as well? Delimiters is not the only thing I added.

Comment: Ok. It I got some bad news for you. The syntax is correct and would allow to register this trigger. However, MySQL does not support modifying the table on which trigger is created.

Comment: Some more restrictions here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/stored-program-restrictions.html